# What is the term for hosted code?

Tags: terminology

What is the term for hosted code?

By this, I mean how you can download jQuery or Bootstrap and have it on your server to use, but you also have the option to link your code to an external code hosting server.

Here is jQuery as hosted by Google:
`ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js`

I could have sworn there is a specific word for this. It would really help when googling for hosted versions of code. I would be able to search for "(term) jquery" and find it a whole lot easier.

Thanks

**EDIT**
My last example was a terrible one because of my mis-understanding of PHP

Comment: I don't understand your example. The jQuery file is a static file, which is different than a PHP SDK which will need some computation by a PHP server.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm new to php and I need the SDK, but was hoping to not have to host it on my server. I thought it would work like css or js where I could just link to it and pull it in to the code.

Comment: There is some websites where you can send PHP to run it, but this is for tests only, not to run real-life code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually it's called "CDN hosted" where CDN means "Content Distribution Network" or "[Content Delivery Network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network)".

In your case, just add CDN to any search terms and you'll usually narrow it down a lot better. For example, jQuery has a CDN option listed on their [download options](http://jquery.com/download/) page.